# How to send an UIViewController that conforms UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

```
func openGallery(sender: AnyObject) {
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = sender
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    sender.navigationController?.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I want to organize my `UIViewControllers` to have all the imagepicker methods in one place. I want to somehow write this method and get it working. Since I am accessing cameras from multiple classes I don't want to make 'sender' a specific `ViewController` class name, that would defeat the whole purpose. Whatever I try to put in the place of 'AnyObject' I get a warning about `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` & `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

I tried this type of solutions too didn't work cause I need both delegates:

```
var newSender = sender as UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
```

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need for your cast is **Protocol Composition**.

Quoting from "*The Swift Programming Language*", p. 545:

> You can combine multiple protocols into a single requirement with a *protocol composition*. Protocol compositions have the form `protocol<SomeProtocol, AnotherProtocol>`. You can list as many protocols within the pair of angle brackets (`<>`) as you need, separated by commas.

Here's how you can apply this concept to your specific case:

```
imagePicker.delegate = sender as? protocol<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: I tried cast class UIViewController as UIImagePickerControllerDelegate and delegate it to UIImagePicker, it compiled, but imagePickerControllerDidCancel never called

Comment: ah! forgot UINavigationControllerDelegate